# How do I get daily Konami rewards with minimum spoilers/effort?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am playing on Steam.

I am going to play MGS:PeaceWalker (on PS3), then Ground Zeros (PC), then Phantom Pain (PC).
But I will be missing out so many daily konamin rewards, like those real money coins.
Konami states that you need to reach some point in the game (main campaign I assume) before getting daily rewards.

So the questions are -

1. How far into the game? How many hours or completion percentage?
2. How many spoilers are there?
3. I haven't played Ground Zeros yet, I know there is an option to upload/download saves whatever. Can I utilize this option later, if reach "reward point" now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You just have to finish the prologue. So, about 1%. (This is my guess and solely based on my own experience. I'm currently at 3% completion, and the only significant plot related thing that happened was the prologue.)
2. It's plot heavy. It introduces several of the main characters you'll be facing through the entire game.
3. Yes. GZ saves are specific rewards. No matter when you do it you'll get the same rewards. The more you complete in GZ the more rewards you'll get.

Comment: Can I restart the campaign later, keeping all the rewards?

Comment: Are you referring to the GZ rewards?

Comment: I am referring to free daily rewards. I want to just reach this point and start gathering the rewards, then replay the game from the beginning, after completing GZ. Is it possible to start a new game? (Phantom Pain does not allow me to see menu from the start, only another cutscene). Will daily rewards be kept or discarded when starting new game? Are there multiple save slots for several games, or only one, like, in diablo 3 for example?